# Yii2 не удается загрузить rar файл!

Tags: yii2, валидация, fileupload, rar, mime-type

Проблема в том, что я загружаю уже второй случайный тестовый файл "rar" и у него mimeType "application/x-rar".
А вот ссылка на файл, который подключается при проверке mimeTypes в Yii2 https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/helpers/mimeTypes.php

Там у "rar" разрешен только один mimeType "application/x-rar-compressed".
Погуглил, советуют отключить проверку по mimeType.
Но мне кажется это не совсем безопасным решением. Я поглядываю в сторону отнаследоваться от FileValidator и дальше уже что-то думать.
Подскажите правильный выход из ситуации без костылей.

Спасибо заранее за ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Вышел из ситуации создав собственный валидатор, поручив на него проверку mimeType в разрезе расширения